# jQuery animations on a mobile device

Tags: jquery

I'm running some jQuery animations on a mobile device.  The animations are laggy and jerky.  Is there anything that can be done to improve this?

Answer (score 0):

This library helps to bridge the gap between jQuery and native CSS animation very well I've found:

http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/

Answer (score 0):

Apply this style to the element you’re animating, it forces webkit to share the processing load with the GPU

```
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
```

You could grab some useful pointers from this [slide](http://standardista.com/velocity/)